# ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy'] Exit Code 1

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, anaconda, conda

I have been searching all over the place but I don't seem to be able to find the answer.

Someone has created a module for us to extract data for a project. However when I attempt to run it I get the following error:

> C:\Anaconda3\python.exe I:/Python/Modules/OVSurvey/ExtractRunner.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "I:/Python/Modules/OVSurvey/ExtractRunner.py", line 18, in  import
>   pandas as pd File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_init_.py",
>   line 18, in  raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies
>   {0}".format(missing_dependencies)) ImportError: Missing required
>   dependencies ['numpy']
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I have tried doing the steps below in the command prompt:

```
conda update conda

conda update -y --all

conda install numpy

conda uninstall pandas

conda uninstall numpy

conda install pandas

conda install numpy
```

It seems to have left me with these versions:

> [ Python 3.4.1 ][ Pandas: 0.19.2-np111py34_1 ][ numpy: 1.11.3-py34_0 ]

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you paste the imports in pandas_init.py?

Comment: When in the anaconda navigator, under environments, is numpy installed?

Comment: Can you use 'conda env list' from command prompt and see what environments you have available? You are calling the ExtractRunner against the base (Anaconda) python interpreter. Is that where you have installed the other modules?